# Review of Financial Studies TEX files & Natbib errors when using a .bst different fro chicago + won't let me use \setcitestyle command

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle

I a typesetting a paper to be published in the Review of Financial Studies (RFS) and am using their Latex files to do so.

Besides many other issues, which I have managed to overcome, one has become insuperable: natbib.

I am using Natbib to do my biblio, as required by their class file, and run into two issues:

1. Once I change the bibliography style from "chicago" to any other .bst file I want to use, for example the RFS.bst provided [here](https://www.ivo-welch.info/professional/rfs-styles/) by Professor Ivo Welch, the whole document breaks down indicating "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" for each enry in my .bib file cited in the paper.
2. I am not able to get \setcitestyle{aysep={}} to work. I get two errors: "Undefined control sequence", and "LaTeX Error: Missing \begin document".

I will include a MWE with the link to download the RFS files:

Links to RFS files:

- [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/review-of-financial-studies-latex-template/bdgcyvpjqmbc)
- [RFS Website (par. 3)](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/pages/Instructions_To_Authors)

Link to RFS.bst:

- https://www.ivo-welch.info/professional/rfs-styles/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
\newcommand{\footnoteremember}[2]{\footnote{#2}\newcounter{#1}\setcounter{#1}{\value{footnote}}}
\newcommand{\footnoterecall}[1]{\footnotemark[\value{#1}]}
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\gdef\copyrightline{Published by Oxford %
University Press on behalf of The Society for Financial Studies 2014.}
\makeatother

\def\DOI{Sample}
\def\volumenumber{00}
\def\volumeissue{0}
\def\volumeyear{2015}

\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}

\setcounter{page}{1}

\access{Advance Access publication September 21, 2014}

%\def\querybox#1{\protect\fboxsep=0pt\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}

\def\mystar{\relax}

\def\tciLaplace{\mathcal{L}}
\def\dint{\mathop{\displaystyle \int}}%

\begin{document}

\title{Strategic Investment and Industry Risk Dynamics\protect\footnote{blablabla}}

\shorttitle{Strategic Investment and Industry Risk Dynamics}

\author{M. Cecilia {Bustamante}}
\affiliation{University of Maryland and London School of Economics}

\abstract{blablabla \JEL{G12, G31}\history{Received XXXX XX, XXXX;
editorial decision XXXX XX, XXXX by Editor
XXXXXXXXXXXX.}}

\maketitle

blablabla

a \cite{Cocco}\\
b \cite{Const1990}\\
c \cite{CC1999}\\

\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{rfs}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

These are some example biblio entries:

```
@article{Cocco,
  author={Joao F. Cocco},
  title={{Consumption and Portfolio Choice over the Life Cycle}},
  journal={Review of Financial Studies},
  year=2005,
  volume={18},
  number={2},
  pages={491-533},
  month={},
  keywords={},
  doi={},
}

@article{Const1990,
 ISSN = {00223808, 1537534X},
 URL = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/2937698},
 author = {George M. Constantinides},
 journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
 number = {3},
 pages = {519--543},
 publisher = {University of Chicago Press},
 title = {Habit Formation: A Resolution of the Equity Premium Puzzle},
 volume = {98},
 year = {1990}
}



@article{CC1999,
title = {Force of Habit: A Consumption-Based Explanation of Aggregate Stock Market Behavior},
author = {Campbell, John and Cochrane, John},
year = {1999},
journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
volume = {107},
number = {2},
pages = {205-251},
url = {https://EconPapers.repec.org/RePEc:ucp:jpolec:v:107:y:1999:i:2:p:205-251}
}
```

Comment: After changing the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, one often has to delete all aux files, including the bbl file, and then perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more. Incidentally, if the RFS's editorial staff is instructing you to use a certain template and to employ a specific bibliography style, you have nothing to gain, and a lot to lose, from not sticking to the journal's explicit instructions. (Last, and maybe least, Prof. Welch's first name is spelled "Ivo", not "Evo".)

Comment: Hey Mico, thanks for the response, and I apologize for the misspelling. Unfortunately, your proposed solution does not resolve the issue given that I have tried running the code both locally and on Overleaf.
Moreover, the RFS provides guidance o how they want citations to look like, but no .bst file to complement other Latex files. That is why I wanted to resort to Professor Ivo Welch's contribution.

Comment: Please edit the postings to show the 3 bib entries ref1, ref2, and ref3.

Comment: Done @Mico, thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm very sorry I can't get your code to work with the RFS template files. I keep getting error messages which I simply don't know how to fix. Very sorry I can't help more directly.